how to resolve defunct overlaps conflict in accurev in GUI/ command prompt
I'm trying to resolve deep overlap in accurev.
Having a file conflict (defunct)overlaps conflict. I have to tried to merge / include to a workspace. but I cant merge / include.It is througing the error specific file not in the workspace.
Is there way to resolve this defunct overlaps.


Find the highest stream in your stream structure that is clear of all the conflicts.
Build a workspace off of THAT stream, defunct the file, and promote.
Work your way DOWN the tree and "Revert To Backed" every place the file appears.

